# Can't install Cashier ~6.0 on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I'm following the instructions via https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing
to setup cashier and hopefully Stripe!

Here's a portion of my composer.json

```
"type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravel/cashier": "~6.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
```

Here's my evidence that Cashier is in (via terminal)

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/cashier (v6.0.0)
  - Installing laravel/cashier (v6.0.17)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
```

And here's a portion of my `/config/app.php`

```
 Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
 Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
```

and then the error

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider' not found
```

I've ran the following commands

- `php artisan`: to see if cashier is available and it is not
- `composer update` but there's nothing to update
- `composer require laravel/cashier=~6.0` but there's nothing to update

Comment: Did you try composer dump ?

Comment: @manshu hey! tried and the issue persists

Comment: Remove the composer.lock file then do composer install

Comment: @manshu `composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update` still getting the nothing to install or update and the error overall

Comment: Delete the composer.lock file and vendor folder. Try doing composer install

Comment: @manshu so during the long install list I saw ` - Installing laravel/cashier (v6.0.17)
    Loading from cache
` and `Installing stripe/stripe-php (v3.14.1)
    Downloading: 100% ` so there must be something else..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113688/discussion-between-manshu-and-markus-proctor).

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

Try these commands, and run composer install && composer update.

Comment: `[LogicException]                                              
  Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.` error from terminal

Comment: Check routes file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. my route for get "/" is just to render a view